# php timer at server side

Tags: php, javascript

I am using php any mysql. I would like to create a timer that operates in the server side, and when time reaches a certain value (e.g. 06:00:00), it can trigger the running of another file (such as, update data of a table).

Actually, what kind of technique I shall use apart from php?

Thankyou...

Comment: what would be practical use of this timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously if you can use them -  cronjobs are the correct solution. But if you just have a little webspace or something where you cant setup cronjobs you need something else. You could of course just do it in php but this istn nice, as you have no guarantee that it runs at specified time, maybe it will much later.
The perfect solution to that scenario ist something like a webcron:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163476/free-alternative-to-webcron

Answer (score 6):

You should look into [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you need to use a cron job here is a decent tutorial for you!

[Link](http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/)

Answer (score 2):

You need [cron jobs](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cron%20job&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron&ei=fSqpTp_BGc3rObeetR0&usg=AFQjCNFFJIlg-yvhmJjB9vc1tkJtgWkSCA) for unix systems and [task schedular](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=task%20scheduler&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler&ei=PSqpTp23KcaxhAeB_4j0DQ&usg=AFQjCNEA35Ofz6JGQs5PwoCZk_v0zK37mQ) for Microsoft systems.

It runs files when you set it to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want events to occur on specific times on the server, use `crontab` to achieve this on Linux servers or `Scheduled Tasks` on Windows servers. You can then schedule the execution of a task at a specific time.